# How to store PHP+HTML script into one variable and insert that variable into MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't know is this possible or not. My requirement is like this:

```
<?php
$str=<<<abc
$sql=mysql_query("select * from links where column='value'");
$sq1=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$s1=$rec[13];
$s2='Done';
if($s1==$s2) {
<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
<input type=hidden name=income value=$rec[value]>
<input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 disabled=\"disabled\">
</form>
}
else
<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
<input type=hidden name=uname value=$rec[value]>
<input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 ">
</form>
abc;        
?>
```

I don't know the above format is correct or not. Please suggest supportable format.

In above format I used to store PHP+HTML script into `str` variable. I heard about `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialcharecters()` functions but I don't know how to use those.

If the value is inserted those value will be accessed from front end using `mysql_fetch_row()` to display those inserted values.

If above is supportable suggest me with good example. If not then suggest which is better to store PHP+HTML script into variable.

MySQL supports this type of queries.

Help any one

Great thanks.

Comment: I think it is probably always wrong to put code like that in your DB. I know that doesn't answer your question, but there is almost certainly a better way of achieving what you are trying to do.

Comment: I feel a tremor in the Force

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using the heredoc syntax which functions like double-quoted strings. That means that variables in the contents are expanded.

As of PHP 5.3 you can use nowdoc syntax which is

> to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to double-quoted strings

Source: [PHP Manual on Nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

This example demostrates the usage of this syntax:

```
$name = 'MyName';

$str = <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name".
EOT;

echo $str;
```

This will output

> My name is "$name".

You can store the contents of $str into an appropriate database field after sanitizing it for the insertion SQL query.

Comment: Good, But I want to display form button based on condition I dont know how it to be achieved,the above condition needs to execute php script I dont know heredoc will support this.Main scenario is I want to display form button in user panel to accept or not some links.Anyone suggest me best idea how to achieve this Great thanks.

Comment: Your question actually was how to store PHP+HTML into a variable. Probably you should open another question on this issue of the conditional form button. If you want to execute the stored php script, use eval().

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with comments above. You should `NOT` do that.
However, you have several problems in your code :

- On the `else` submit button, you have a `"` at the end that should not be there.
- You have HTML inside the PHP, with no `echo` calls.
- You have trailing spaces after the `abc` string.
- The `;` after the `abc` string should be on a new line.

Here is the "correct" code :

```
<?php
$str=<<<abc
$sql=mysql_query("select * from links where column='value'");
$sq1=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$s1=$rec[13];
$s2='Done';
if($s1==$s2)
{
echo "
<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
<input type=hidden name=income value=$rec[value]>
<input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 disabled=\"disabled\">
</form>
";
}
else
echo "
<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
<input type=hidden name=uname value=$rec[value]>
<input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 />
</form>";
abc
;

echo $str;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Mostly ok But when I try to save it into database using registration form it shows error messages like undefined variable sql,s1,rec in in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: Well, without the error message, and the code generating the error, it's hard to help.